# Show that $[x]$ generates the set of units for $R = \mathbb F_3[x]/\langle x^2+x+2\rangle$

Tags: polynomials, ideals

Given $R = \mathbb F_3[x]/\langle x^2+x+2\rangle$, which I have previously shown is a field with $9$ elements, I now have to show that $[x]$ generates $R^*$, the set of units of $R.$ In other words, I have to show that $\langle [x]\rangle = R^*.$

My logic shows that I have misunderstood something fundamental:

Since $R$ is a field, we must have $R^* = R \setminus \{[0]\}.$

Since $\langle [x]\rangle = \{ k[x] \ | \ k \in R \}$ we must have $[0][x] = [0x] = [0] \in \langle [x]\rangle.$

But this is in contradiction with $\langle [x]\rangle = R^* = R \setminus \{[0]\}. $

What am I misunderstanding and how can I show that $\langle [x]\rangle = R^*?$

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts! That made it easy to identify what your misunderstanding was. If only all the askers where equally willing (and able) to share their thoughts. +1 has been there as a matter of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you missed is that $R^*$ is a multiplicative group, and the question is about the multiplicative subgroup generated by the coset $[x]$.

Therefore 
$$\langle [x]\rangle=\{[x^t]\mid t\in\Bbb{Z}\}.$$
When proving that $\langle[x]\rangle=R^*$ it is beneficial to observe that $R^*$ has exactly eight elements (do you why?). Therefore it suffices to check that  $[x^4]\neq[1]$. Do you see why?

Comment: To be honest, i'm quite confused. Since $[x] \in R$, which is a ring, how am i supposed to know that $\langle [x] \rangle$ is not an ideal, but the set that you mention. (This is from an old exam set)

Comment: The catch is that $R^*$ is neither a ring nor an ideal. It is "only" a group. A further point is that it is a standard result that the multiplicative group of a finite field is always cyclic. Therefore locating a generator for the multiplicative group becomes an interesting question. Admittedly, if that result was not covered before this point (a live possibility!), then this extra argument is not compelling to you. The main point is that the only structure $R^*$ has is that of a multiplicative group, and therefore this is the only intepretation of "generates".

Comment: @mikkelmk Just to add to what Jyrki has said... I agree that the question from that exam is slightly confusing, I would phrase it differently if I was setting up the exam (e.g. "prove that $[x]$ is a generator of the multiplicative group $R^*$...") However, it is really hard to think of any other interpretation. (The one with the ring/ideal certainly doesn't work, and you are pretty much left with this other one!)

Comment: Aight, i got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$\langle[x]\rangle$ is not to be understood as the "ideal" in the field (which would coincide with the whole field, of course). It should be just understood as a subgroup of $R^*$ generated by $[x]$, i.e. $\{[x]^n\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}=\{[x^n]\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$

For that, because the order of $R^*$ is $8$, you just need to prove that the order of $[x]$ is $8$. Do it by proving that it is not $1$, $2$ or $4$, i.e. that $[x]\ne[1]$, $[x^2]=[2x+1]\ne[1]$ and $[x^4]=[(2x+1)^2]=[x^2+x+1]=[2]\ne [1]$.